# Why typedef for a function pointer is different from a regular typedef?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, typedef

`typedef` regularly works like: `typedef <type> <type_alias>`. But typedefs for function pointers seems to have different structure: `typedef int (*fn)(char *, char *);` - there is no type alias, just a single function signature.

Here is the example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*callback)(int);

void range(int start, int stop, callback cb) {
    int i;
    for (i = start; i < stop; i++) {
        (*cb)(i);
    }
}

void printer(int i) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

main(int argc, int *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Provide 2 arguments - start and stop!");
    }

    range(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), printer);
}
```

So - why `typedef`s for function pointers are different?

Comment: It's the same as how you declare a function pointer variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same. You just have to look at it in a slightly different way. `typedef` defines your own type name by putting it in exactly the place where the identifier of your variable would go without the `typedef`. So

```
uint8_t foo;
```

becomes

```
typedef uint8_t footype;
footype foo;
```

**edit**: so "R Sahu" was a bit faster and see his example for the same principle applied to function pointers.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the standard?

Comment: It's specified in [6.7.7 p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.7p3). (key phrase: "in the way described in 6.7.5")

Comment: Look [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.7p7),  `typedef void fv(int), (*pfv)(int);` - notice, no return type for the second function declaration. So it turns out, that `typedef` associates `void` type with the following function signatures. So you can write `typedef void fn1(int), (*fnptr1)(int), fn2(char *), ...;`

Comment: That's just the normal way the comma works in declarations. Remove the `typedef` and see what it means.

Comment: Btw a perfect example to show how C declarations can look *really* obfuscated. That's probably the reason why [sites like this](http://cdecl.org/) exist ;) [note this site doesn't understand the comma ... haha]

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for using `typedef` to define a function pointer type follows the same syntax as you would use for defining function pointers.

```
int (*fn)(char *, char *);
```

Defines `fn` to be a pointer to a function `...`

```
typedef int (*fn)(char *, char *);
```

Defines `fn` to be a type that is a pointer to a function `...`

Answer (score 1):

C declaration syntax is much more complicated than `type identifier`, with examples like

```
T (*ap)[N];             // ap is a pointer to an N-element array
T *(*f())();            // f is a function returning a pointer to
                        // a function returning a pointer to T
```

Syntactically, `typedef` is treated as a storage class specifier like `static` or `extern`.  So you can add `typedef` to each of the above, giving

```
typedef T (*ap)[N];     // ap is an alias for type "pointer to N-element array
typedef T *(*f())();    // f is an alias for type "function returning
                        // pointer to function returning pointer to T"
```